# Pasting from vim to a buffer of emacs

Tags: evil, copy-paste, tmux

I am rocking quite an idiosyncratic workflow that combines both vim and emacs in a tmux session, on an ssh server. The problem is, if I try to copy (`y`) something from a (neo)vim buffer and paste in an emacs one, I can't paste it using evil's `p`.

On the contrary, pasting from one instance of vim to another (either vim or neovim) works quite well maybe since I have `set clipboard^=unnamed,unnamedplus` in my `.vimrc`.

What config should I set in emacs to get it work well with vim, regarding inter-application copying and pasting? I always resort to tmux's copy-and-paste functions, but it's too slow when the region to copy is large.

Comment: This sounds like a clipboard issue - i.e., Emacs and vim are using different ones. I find using `SHIFT-INSERT` or middle-click with the mouse usually gets around it. You may find this information helpful. [EmacsWiki: Copy and Paste](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CopyAndPaste)

Comment: @naugiedoggie Thanks for the info. It does indeed seem like a clipboard issue; vim and evil-enabled emacs are carrying separate set of registers with no single register overlapping. The solution would be to expose the ssh machine's clipboard to the both, but I'm not sure how.